# How to create editable custom field in Django admin interfce

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a property inside a model and I want to make the admin interface to relate to that property. I don't find any easy way to do that.

The model property:

```
@property
def weight(self):
        weight_unit = self.restaurant.weight_unit
        if weight_unit is WeightUnits.KG:
            return self.weight_kg
        if weight_unit is WeightUnits.OZ:
            return Weight(kg=self.weight_kg).oz  

@weight.setter
def weight(self, value):
        weight_unit = self.restaurant.weight_unit
        if weight_unit is WeightUnits.KG:
            self.weight_kg = value
        if weight_unit is WeightUnits.OZ:
            self.weight_kg = Weight(oz=self.weight_kg).kg
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Add this under your model admin:

```
def get_weight(self, obj):
        return obj.weight
weight.short_description = 'Weight'
```